# How to place a frame under another frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a layout which consists of left frame with multiple radial charts and scrollbar, upper middle frame which shows line plot, lower middle frame to show a table image, and right frame to show another kind of radial chart.

How can I place the table chart image under line plot? This frame should have same size as line plot frame size.

Here is the image of my expected layout:

[image]

Besides, here is my implementation:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# Create the main Tkinter window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Radial Charts")
root.geometry("1200x600")

# Create the main frame
main_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
main_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

# Create the left frame with a scrollbar
left_frame = ttk.Frame(main_frame)
left_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# Create a canvas for the radial charts
canvas = tk.Canvas(left_frame)
canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# Create a vertical scrollbar for the radial charts canvas
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(left_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

# Configure the canvas to use the scrollbar
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all')))

# Create a frame inside the canvas to hold the radial charts
frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame, anchor=tk.NW)

# Create the upper middle frame for the line plot
upper_middle_frame = ttk.Frame(main_frame, width=500, height=600)
upper_middle_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# Create the lower middle frame
lower_middle_frame = ttk.Frame(main_frame)
lower_middle_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# Create a canvas for the line plot
line_plot_canvas = tk.Canvas(upper_middle_frame, width=500, height=600, background='white')
line_plot_canvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH)

# Load and display the radial charts
checkbuttons = []  # List to store the checkbuttons
selected_checkbuttons = []  # List to store the selected checkbuttons
line_plot_image = None  # Global variable to store line plot image
line_plot_image_tk = None  # Global variable to store line plot image in Tkinter format


def generate_line_plot_path(start_visit, end_visit):
    line_plot_path = f"path/line_plot_{start_visit}_and_{end_visit}.png"
    return line_plot_path


def display_line_plot():
    line_plot_canvas.delete("all")  # Clear the line plot canvas
    if line_plot_image:
        # Adjust the desired width and height values
        desired_width = 900
        desired_height = 600

        # Resize the line plot image
        resized_image = line_plot_image.resize((desired_width, desired_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        # Convert the resized image to Tkinter-compatible format
        global line_plot_image_tk
        line_plot_image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)

        # Display the resized line plot image on the canvas
        line_plot_canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, image=line_plot_image_tk)


# Function to handle checkbox selection
def checkbox_selected():
    global line_plot_image  # Declare line_plot_image as a global variable
    selected_checkbuttons.clear()
    for cb, var in checkbuttons:
        if var.get() == 1:
            selected_checkbuttons.append(cb)
    if len(selected_checkbuttons) >= 2:
        start_visit = int(selected_checkbuttons[0]["text"].split("_")[1])
        end_visit = int(selected_checkbuttons[1]["text"].split("_")[1])
        line_plot_path = generate_line_plot_path(start_visit, end_visit)

        line_plot_image = Image.open(line_plot_path)
        line_plot_image = line_plot_image.resize((500, 600), Image.ANTIALIAS)  # Adjust the size as needed

        display_line_plot()


# Load and display the radial charts
for i in range(1, 10):
    image_path = f"path/visit_{i}.png"  # Replace with the actual image path

    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image = image.resize((400, 400), Image.ANTIALIAS)  # Adjust the size as needed
    image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    # Create a label to display the image
    label = tk.Label(frame, image=image_tk)
    label.pack()

    # Keep a reference to the image to prevent it from being garbage collected
    label.image = image_tk

    # Create an IntVar for each Checkbutton
    check_var = tk.IntVar()

    # Create a Checkbutton and place it on the bottom-right part of the image
    checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(label, text=f"visit_{i}", variable=check_var, command=checkbox_selected)
    checkbutton.place(relx=1, rely=1, anchor=tk.SE)

    checkbuttons.append((checkbutton, check_var))  # Add the checkbutton and its associated variable to the list

# Start the Tkinter event loop
root.mainloop()
```

I would appreciate any help to show table_1_2.png under the Line Plot. If user chooses checkbox 1 and 2, line_plot_1_2 and table_1_2 should be shown. If 3 and 4 are chosen, then line_plot_3_4 and table_3_4 should be shown.

How can I add lower_middle_frame to show table image?

Comment: An easy approach that I often use is to place the `Frame`s you want to "stack" (in this case, Line Plot and Table) into a container `Frame`, `pack`ing the upper `Frame` (Line Plot) with `side='top'` and the lower `Frame` (Table) with `side='bottom'

Comment: @JRiggles I tried this approach. But, radial charts ended up being shown on the right instead of left. How to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough example of how to stack your widgets in a parent `Frame`. I've created two `Frame`s here, `container_left` and `container_right`. When you `pack` the widgets into `container_right` (or anywhere else, for that matter), they'll stack from the top-down since `side='top'` is the default behavior of the `pack` geometry manager

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


root = tk.Tk()
# place your 'radial plots' in this frame
container_left = tk.Frame(root)
container_left.pack(expand=True, fill='both', side='left')

# place your 'line plot' and 'table' in this frame
container_right = tk.Frame(root)
container_right.pack(expand=True, fill='both', side='right')

line_plot = tk.Canvas(container_right, ...)  # ... code omitted for brevity
line_plot.pack(...)  # no need to specify 'side' here as 'top' is the default

table = ttk.Treeview(container_right, ...)
table.pack(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't be afraid to create extra frames to help with your layout. In this case I would create a frame to  hold all three of the items on the right. Then, you can pack each one to the top, in whichever order you want.

Comment: Could you please provide me a basic example of this? Do you mean using a main frame?